# Is there any platform where someone could check very complex equation rewrite (analytical derivation)

Tags: derivatives

So just to be clear, I am at postgrad level, not asking for answers to school homework. So I have a very complex mathematical model which I need to simply so that I can take derivative of the model (analytically with respective to one of it parameters, lets say A.
Derivatives, simple enough right?

But this model involves other hidden multiple equations that are functions of A. Really tedious but doable, and I have done it. The issue is that because of so many steps I have taken, I'm pretty sure I must have made mistakes somewhere but its vastness just swallows me up and I'd like a few other people double checking my work. Obviously I will ask my fellow postgrads but was wondering if there are some sort of platform (if it is not acceptable on stackexchange) that I can ask someone to go over my work? or softwares?

Just for the sake of it the model is:

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUz1V.jpg)

Basically I need to take derivative of TCP_combined wrt D_i. Unless equations are given, all parameters are constants.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I think asking on Stackexchange is fine, but probably not many people will have the motivation to check such computations. On the other hand, yes, there are softwares for things like that. I'm not really a speacialist, but as far as free softwares are concerned, there is Sage (most of them are not free, though).

Comment: Any [computer algebra system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) should be able to help with this.